# RhinoMocks Types

Tags: mocking, rhino-mocks

Folks

How to  Exposte RhinoMock Objects as properties

I am trying following code snippet

```
   internal class Mocks
    {
        private MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFormsAuthentication> formsAuthentication;
    }
```

but its now working for me anyone know How to do this with rhinomocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFormsAuthentication>()
```

is a method, not a Type.

It looks like what you're looking to do is this:

```
internal class Mocks    
{
    private IFormsAuthentication formsAuthentication;    

    internal Mocks()
    {
        formsAuthentication = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFormsAuthentication>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank buddy this is was I was looking for but now i am running into different Issue

 internal class Mocks
    {
        private static IFormsAuthentication _formsAuthentication;
        
        public IFormsAuthentication FormsAuthentication
        {
            get
            {
              
                _formsAuthentication = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFormsAuthentication>();
                return _formsAuthentication;
            }
        }

Comment: What problem are you having exactly? You might want to edit your question instead of commenting here, it will have a better format.